# ERROR:@google-cloud/error-reporting: Encountered an error while attempting to transmit an error to the Stackdriver Error Reporting API

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to add an error reporting in a nodejs app which will report errors to stackdriver api on GCP. I have followed all the steps required to report an error but when I report error I'm getting an error

```
ERROR:@google-cloud/error-reporting: Encountered an error while attempting to transmit an error to the Stackdriver Error Reporting API. ApiError: User not authorized.
```

The entire error stack is

```
ERROR:@google-cloud/error-reporting: Encountered an error while attempting to transmit an error to the Stackdriver Error Reporting API. ApiError: User not authorized.
    at new ApiError (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web-dev/kiddopia.com/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:59:15)
    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web-dev/kiddopia.com/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:194:38)
    at Util.handleResp (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web-dev/kiddopia.com/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:135:117)
    at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web-dev/kiddopia.com/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:434:22
    at onResponse (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web-dev/kiddopia.com/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:214:7)
    at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web-dev/kiddopia.com/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:219:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

My error reporting helper is

```
const { ErrorReporting } = require('@google-cloud/error-reporting');

module.exports = class ErrorReportHelper {
    constructor() {
        this.errorReporter = new ErrorReporting({
            projectId: 'project-id',
            reportMode: 'always',
            keyFilename: 'service.json'
        });
    }
    report(message) {
        this.errorReporter.report(message);
    }
    express() {
        return this.errorReporter.express();
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details about "I have followed all the steps required to report". Which documentation guide have you followed? Which which permissions you're running your application? Which GCP product do you use?

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: I created another service with errorreporting.admin role and it worked

Comment: I couldn't find stackdriver error reporting api, is it discontinued?

Comment: @rawrstar https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/ here's the link for the logging API that reports logs to stackdriver error reporting

Comment: @RahulBharati Its just called error reporting api now, its no more called Stackdriver, so I was able to find it https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com?project=active-cable-354710

Comment: Ensure that your project ID is accurate...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Error Reporting Writer" permission to your service account/application through google console:

1. Go to google console https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam
2. Select your project
3. IAM & Admin -> IAM
4. Locate the main service account for your app
5. Click "edit" next to the service account
6. Scroll down and click "add another role"
7. Locate "Error Reporting Writer" and add it

Make sure it's saved and you should be good.